# Granule - JavaScript/CSS minification SIMPLE/ADVANCED optimization is not working

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, minify, google-closure-compiler

I setup [Granule optimization solution](https://github.com/JonathanWalsh/Granule) on fly (not build process) for my web application by following the installation steps at the bottom of this page: https://github.com/JonathanWalsh/Granule
Granule uses [Closure Compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/) for compressing and minifying JavaScript and CSS files.

In the properties file I played with some of the settings turning on/off. It works pretty good...

When I tried to set the closure-compiler.compilation_level setting (values: WHITESPACE_ONLY/SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS/ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS) the combined file is not changing. It just removes white spaces when I set it to SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS or ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS. It is not using the simple/advanced minification algorithms.

Does anybody has any experience with this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to include Granule-Closure-Compiler (https://github.com/JonathanWalsh/Granule-Closure-Compiler) in your web-inf/lib dir